# Creating a mutual friends list

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've been through the Treebook tutorial on Treehouse and I've been trying to enhance it.

I want to add a list of mutual friends on the profile_page that shows the friends you have in common with that user.

I can write an if statement to show the profile_name of the common users.

E.g.

```
    <% if current_user.friends.include?(friend) and @user.friends.include?(friend) %>
      <%= friend.profile_name %>
    <% end %>
```

But I'd like to write a block to go through and show other information. How would I create the query in the profiles controller so that I can use it in the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received some help elsewhere. I'm guilty of overthinking the problem.

```
@common_friends = current_user.friends & @user.friends
```

Then used:

```
  <% @common_friends.each do |friend|%>
  <%= friend.profile_name %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like:

```
def common_friends
   Friends.where(friends: [friend1, friend2])
end
```

This way you are querying for friends where friend list includes both friend1 and friend2.